# Getting a Phd abroad: is there any chance?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I am Earth Sciences major with post-graduate studies (Master) in the field of Geophysics/Seismology from Greece. In the last couple of months i am trying to find a PhD opportunity abroad in order to continue my research journey. I think i have built a pretty good CV for my level (and young age) with good grades, numerous poster presentations and 4 peer reviewed publications in well known journals in my field. Is it possible to find a PhD in a prestigious University abroad, based on a good CV with degrees (Bsc, Msc) from Greek University? Any advise or experience is more than welcome.

Thank You!

Comment: The only way to get a valid answer is to ask the universities you contemplate attending. Usually the best way is to actually apply. Nothing in what you say sounds like it would be a problem, of course. But the competition at "prestigious" universities is quite intense.

Comment: I'll also note that Greece is part of the [Bologna Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bologna_Process), so within EU, there should be many opportunities. Elsewhere also, of course.

Comment: If you're considering the US as part of "abroad", keep in mind that most US graduate programs operate on a standard admissions calendar, with applications for fall admission typically due the previous December.

Comment: Would it be useful to approach via e-mail potential PhD supervisors?

Comment: I'd also separate the problems of "getting into a PhD program" and "being funded". In my location you can relatively easily get into a PhD program at a good university, while getting a scholarship can be much, much harder.

Comment: @JohnF yes, I think it would be useful to contact potential supervisors directly. You might not get an answer most of the time, but that will certainly increase your chances: a lot of PhD positions are not advertised (or not much), direct contact can put you in the loop for positions you wouldn't know about.

Answer (score 4):

> Getting a Phd [outside of Greece]: is there any chance?

TL;DR: **Yes**

> I think i have built a pretty good CV for my level (and young age) with good grades, numerous poster presentations and 4 peer reviewed publications in well known journals in my field.

Many universities will accept PhD students without any publications, so - with *4 peer reviewed publications* - you seem like a good candidate.* You don't say how good your grades are, PhD students will typically be amongst the top of their class.

*I cannot answer specifically for  Earth Sciences.

> Is it possible to find a PhD in a prestigious University [outside of Greece], based
>   on a good CV with degrees (Bsc, Msc) from Greek University?

Yes. You mention, during *the last couple of months i am trying to find a PhD opportunity*, has your search been unsuccessful? If so, why?

Comment: Yes, i applied to two different PhD calls. I received standardized e-mail rejections.

Comment: @JohnF two applications is not enough, you should probably target at least a dozen to get a decent chance overall.